# Mapping subdomain to a different home page in my app hosted on google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, dns

I recently added a domain(example.com) for my app hosted on GAE.
I have added one more subdomain (test.example.com)
Now I want that whenever user visits test.example.com he should get a different home page than the example.com home page.
P.S. Both the domains are going to use the app's internal data store,but i need to show different home page.

Answer (score 3):

Using [webapp2 extra routes](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/routes.html), you can create a `DomainRoute`:

```
from webapp2 import Route, WSGIApplication
from webapp2_extras.routes import DomainRoute

routes = [
    DomainRoute('test.example.com', [
        Route('/', handler='handlers.TestHomeHandler')
    ]),
    Route('/', handler='handlers.HomeHandler')
]
app = WSGIApplication(routes=routes, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the domain using following code and redirect the page accordingly

```
if "test.example.com" in self.request.host_url:
    self.redirect('/test_home')
else:
    self.redirect('/home')
```

and if you want to pass a query string to the home page, then redirect will like this

```
self.redirect('/test_home?'+ self.request.query_string)
```